# Adding objects to an arrayList, until the user inputs "no"

Tags: java, arraylist

I wish to add objects to an arrayList until user inputs "no" in a Do While loop, I can't make it work, this is what I have so far:

```
 ArrayList<Humano> lista = new ArrayList<>();
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {

        Humano h = new Humano();
        System.out.println("Name");
        h.setNombre(input.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Age");
        h.setEdad(input.nextInt());
        lista.add(h);
        System.out.println("wish to continue?");

    } while ();//user inputs "no"
```

Class, attributes, setters and getters.

```
public class Humano {

private String nombre;
private int edad;


public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public int getEdad() {
    return edad;
}

public void setEdad(int edad) {
    this.edad = edad;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import java.util.Scanner;  
import java.util.*;

public class Test
{
     public static void main(String []args){
         ArrayList lista = new ArrayList();
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         String userInput;
         do {
            System.out.println("Name");
            lista.add(input.nextLine());
            System.out.println("SurName");
            lista.add(input.nextLine());
            System.out.println("wish to continue?");
            userInput = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("your input is " + userInput);
        } while (!userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("NO"));
        //whether user types "no" or "No" or "nO" or "NO", it will consider all cases.
     }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry about that, I forgot to create a string variable. I have edited the post, hope it helps

Comment: Hi, Still doesnt work. when it reach "wish to continue?" the program ends, whitout wait for the user imput

Comment: Please give me a min

Comment: I have edited the solution and tested it on my machine. Please use it as a reference, if you get a error now also, then please edit your post with the complete code. Thanks!

Comment: Weird, your code works, but when I include the attribute: private int edad; in the Human class...it reach "wish to continue?" and the program ends.        do i have to mandatory set all attributes to String?